# Pentaho Data Integration How to run job with kitchen on carte cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I had set up a carte cluster (1 master and 2 slaves) and run a job on carte cluster with spoon. But when I ran with kitchen command or carte http access, it ran as standalone (just run in master node).

Did I miss anything in the configuration? Or doesn't it support cluster mode?

Here was what I tried:

1. my config:

[image]

[image]

2. ran in spoon with "Enviroment Type -- Local"

   master output:

   ```
   2017/11/28 04:47:09 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: /root/.kettle/repositories.xml
   Tue Nov 28 04:47:09 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must   be       established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to   explicitly disable SSL       by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sortcluster111 (master) - Dispatching started for transformation [sortcluster111 (master)]
   Tue Nov 28 04:47:10 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must   be       established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to   explicitly disable SSL       by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   Tue Nov 28 04:47:10 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must   be       established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to   explicitly disable SSL       by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - output.0 - Connected to database [102] (commit=1000)
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - input.0 - Finished processing (I=47, O=0, R=0, W=47, U=0, E=0)
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - input.0 - Server socket accepted for port [40001], reading from server Dynamic slave [kettleslave02:8083]
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - input.0 - Server socket accepted for port [40000], reading from server Dynamic slave [kettleslave01:8082]
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - output.0 - Finished processing (I=47, O=47, R=0, W=47, U=0, E=0)
   ```

   slave01 output:

   ```
   2017/11/28 04:47:09 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: /root/.kettle/repositories.xml
   Tue Nov 28 04:47:09 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must  be        established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to  explicitly disable SSL        by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sortcluster111 (cluster1:Dynamic slave [kettleslave01:8082]) - Dispatching started for transformation [sortcluster111 (cluster1:Dynamic slave [kettleslave01:8082])]
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sort.0 - Server socket accepted for port [40000], reading from server kettlemaster01
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sort.0 - Finished processing (I=24, O=0, R=0, W=24, U=0, E=0)
   ```

   slave02 output:

   ```
   2017/11/28 04:47:09 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: /root/.kettle/repositories.xml
   2017/11/28 04:47:09 - General - Unable to connect to the repository with name 'Mysqlrep'
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sortcluster111 (cluster1:Dynamic slave [kettleslave02:8083]) - Dispatching started for transformation [sortcluster111 (cluster1:Dynamic slave [kettleslave02:8083])]
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sort.0 - Server socket accepted for port [40000], reading from server kettlemaster01
   2017/11/28 04:47:10 - sort.0 - Finished processing (I=23, O=0, R=0, W=23, U=0, E=0)
   ```
3. ran with kitchen:

   ```
   kitchen.sh -rep=Mysqlrep -user=admin -pass=admin -job trans1
   ```

   master output:

   ```
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Starting entry [sorttrans]
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - sorttrans - Loading transformation from repository [sortcluster111] in directory [/]
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - sorttrans - Using run configuration [cluster config]
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - sorttrans - Using legacy execution engine
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - sortcluster111 - Dispatching started for transformation [sortcluster111]
   Tue Nov 28 04:10:19 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be         established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL         by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   Tue Nov 28 04:10:19 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be         established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL         by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - output.0 - Connected to database [102] (commit=1000)
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - input.0 - Finished processing (I=47, O=0, R=0, W=47, U=0, E=0)
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - sort.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=47, W=47, U=0, E=0)
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=47, R=47, W=47, U=0, E=0)
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Starting entry [finish]
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Finished job entry [finish] (result=[true])
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Finished job entry [sorttrans] (result=[true])
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Finished job entry [SQL] (result=[true])
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - trans1 - Job execution finished
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - Kitchen - Finished!
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - Kitchen - Start=2017/11/28 04:10:00.586, Stop=2017/11/28 04:10:19.739
   2017/11/28 04:10:19 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 19 seconds.
   ```

   has no output in the slave

Regards

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in new versions of pdi:
The option "Run this transformation in a clustered mode?" not exists, so to fix that you need open the job xml file and remove the property **run_configuration** and set **cluster** to Y from entry's of transformation that you wanna run in clustered mode.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, start carte on distant server:

- `./carte.sh hostname port`
- check in your browser: `hostname:port/kettle/status/` respond with an empty status page

Second, define carte in spoon:

- in spoon view (left panel): click on `Slave serve`r, then `new`
- server name = carte
- hostname = previously defined hostname
- port = previously defined port
- web app name = **blank** (important!)
- username = cluster
- password = cluster
  Is the master = **Yes**

Third, configure spoon run:

- in spoon view (left panel): click on `Run configuration`, then `new`
- Name: carte/servername
- Engine: Pentaho (default)
- Slave server: Yes
- Location: carte (server name as defined in second step)
- Send resource to this server: Yes (unless you [read the doc](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/030/010#Run_Configurations))

Forth, run the transformaton/job

- the Run configuration drop-down box let you choose between `Pentaho local` or `carte/hostname`, or any configuration defined in third step.
- if you disabled the `Run option` panel, then Drop-down the Run tool or Top menu/Action/Run option or F8. And check the `Always show dialog on run`, you'll need it in the future.

Fifth

- in your browser: `hostname:port/kettle/status/`
- have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't find `slave server` in `Run configuration` in my spoon, I just get `Local` and `Remote` and I choice `Remote` and `Location` is `Clustered`. I can run my job in cluster witn spoon, but it does not work when I use `kitchen` or `hostname:port/kettle/executeJob`.

Comment: My PDI version is 7.1.0.0